# How to download artifacts built with gulp script in azure-pipelines from dist folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am building an electron app which uses gulp script to build the app and place the final `.exe|.deb|.dmg` files at `{root}/dist/desktop` directory. How do I download those files. I do not see any 'Artifacts' section in azure.

Here is my `azure-pipelines.yml` which builds fine.

```
variables:
  node_version: "10.x"

trigger:
  - master

jobs:
  - job: Windows
    pool:
      vmImage: "vs2017-win2016"
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: $(node_version)
      - script: yarn install
      - script: yarn build:desktop-azure

  - job: macOS
    pool:
      vmImage: "macOS-10.14"
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: $(node_version)
      - script: yarn install
      - script: yarn build:desktop-azure

  - job: Linux
    pool:
      vmImage: "ubuntu-16.04"
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: $(node_version)
      - script: yarn install
      - script: yarn build:desktop-azure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in each job add a [Publish Build Artifacts Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts), this task will save the files in Azure DevOps and you will be able to download them (and also get them in the Release):

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
     pathtoPublish: 'path/to/the/dist/desktop/folder'
     artifactName: 'windows/mac/linux-artifacts'
```

[image]